# Python http.server command gives "Syntax Error"

Tags: python

I am trying to start http.server from the Python shell (Python 3.6.2).  In the shell, I issue the following commands:

```
import http.server
import socketserver
python -m http.server 8000 --bind 127.0.0.1
```

The last line comes directly from the latest [Python docs on http.server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html), but the shell says "Syntax Error."

Then I tried :

```
python3 -m http.server 8000 --bind 127.0.0.1
```

But the shell still says "Syntax Error."

Then I tried the simplest command:

```
python -m http.server also says "Syntax Error":
```

But the shell still says "Syntax Error."

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `python -m http.server 8000 --bind 127.0.0.1` it is not a valid command in python. Where did you get that code from?

Comment: As I said, that comes straight from the latest Python docs.

Comment: you want to run that command from your shell, not from  your python interpreter

Comment: I'm running it from the shell as I said -- the Python interactive command line.

Comment: @RTC222 as they point out that command is for the console/shell/CMD, not for the python script.

Comment: @RTC222 `"shell" != "python interactive command line"`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html

Comment: The interactive command line is not the shell.  `python` is a shell executable, but you're trying to use it as a Python command.

Comment: Perhaps what you want is to run it as an `os` or `subprocess` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're having trouble understanding what we mean in the comments; you need to run the command

```
python -m http.server 8000 --bind 127.0.0.1
```

from a bash (or similar) shell, **NOT** from the python IDLE interpreter. They do not mean the same thing. You would have to type the command `python` into your shell in order to get to you Python IDLE interpreter.

If you're in your python interpreter and would like to exit, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to return to your bash (or similar) shell. *Then*, execute the command

```
python -m http.server 8000 --bind 127.0.0.1
```

and it should work.

You are right that the python documentation for httpserver could be made more clear but you should know that when you see a call to `python` it's almost certainly being made from a shell.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I usually develop in my IDE, so I'm not very familiar with using just the Python command line.  The documentation is not clear on this and the research available is also not clear.  Thanks much for clearing that up.

Comment: Stack Overflow does not allow me to accept your answer for several minutes after you post it.  I will when that period elapses.  Thanks much.