# Use http.server command line within python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, http

In the command line, we can do this:
`$ python3 -m http.server 8674`
But in Python code (in .py), how to do this?
P.S. Don't use `os.system`! I'm going to use it in an exe, and that will fail.
P.P.S. Don't suggest [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53769352/python-http-server-command-gives-syntax-error). Really from code, not command line.

Comment: No but I'll suggest reading the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) as there's examples on how to run it in code. It's a module so you can just import it.

Comment: @Torxed see accepted answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is import the `http.server` default module.

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

def run(number=8080, server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    server_address = ('', number)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    try:
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Exit")
```

See [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) for further explanations.

Comment: Why do I get this error: ``code 501, message Unsupported method ('GET')``

Comment: When do you get this error ? Upon launching the server ? You can try to replace BaseHTTPRequestHandler with SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, make sure you import it. See this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40031792/python-ssl-server-gives-me-501-unsupported-method-get

Answer (score 1):

Website can be served through a Python program easily 
by using these 2 modules:

- http.server  (for http)
- socketserver (for TCP port)

**Here is an example of working code:**

```
# File name:  web-server-demo.py

import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 8080
Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print("serving the website at port # ", PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

**Sample index.html file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Website served by Python</title>
  </head>
  <bod>
    <div>
      <h1>Website served by Python program</h2>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

```
> python web-server-demo.py
serving the website at port #  8080
127.0.0.1 - - [25/May/2020 14:19:27] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

[image]

Comment: More information:  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_network_programming/python_http_server.htm